# Retrieving the row count from an html table

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

How can I calculate a grid's row count? My grid has data, but this code returns `0`:

```
alert($('#Grid').data("kendoGrid").tbody.find('>tr.k-master-row').length);
```

Comment: Can you please include a sample of the html for this grid?

Comment: like this http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, one side note: finding the length of a  `grid` based on `tbody` will show you **only** the number of rows in the `view` (those visible) if there is `paging` you will not know those not visible.

There are several options:

1. Based on what you did: `$("#grid").data('kendoGrid').tbody.find('>tr').length`
2. Not having to calculate it (solution 1 might be expensive since it has to count it based on navigating the DOM): `$("#grid").data('kendoGrid').tbody[0].rows.length`
3. Based on `dataSource.view`: `grid.dataSource.view().length`

Answer (score 2):

As OnaBai says, it depends if you want the whole count of lines in the table or only the one visibles.

If you want the **total number of lines**, you can use :

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.total();
```

and if you only want the **visible ones**, you can use :

```
$("#grid").find("tbody > tr").length;
```

Comment: `$("#grid").find("tbody > tr").length;` worked a charm. It is 1 more than my actual row count but I am assuming that is the heading row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this @flower

```
$("#grid").data('kendoGrid').tbody[0].rows.length
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SWnSs/1/